# ¿Como evitar que se cambie el estado a loggedin?

Tags: flutter, firebase-auth

Estoy realizando una autenticación con **Firebase** y **Facebook**, el login funciona sin problema alguno.
antes de cambiar el estado a loggedin quiero revisar unos datos con una **API** externa para lo cual indicara si puede iniciar sesión o no.

El problema es que después de verificar el login con **Facebook** o cualquier otro método de login automáticamente cambia el estado a loggedin antes de poder revisar los datos con la **API**.

He realizado varias pruebas e intentado varias cosas, la ultima que probé y que pensé funcionaria es la siguiente, que es básicamente regresar null de los datos para dar la impresión de que no hay sesión.

```
Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
      _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map((FirebaseUser user) {sesión
        if (user != null) {
          print('Stream user null');
          signOut(); 
        }
        return null;
      });
```

Método login con **Facebook**

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> signInWithFacebook() async {
  try {
    
    final result = await _facebookLogin.logIn(["email"]);
    
    
    final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
    );
    
    final face = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final userFace = face.user;

    final prefs = PreferenciasApp();

    
    // saving data user
    // get photo facebook
    prefs.photoUrl = userFace.photoUrl + '?type=large';
    prefs.idUser = digest.toString();
    prefs.nameUser = userFace.displayName;
    prefs.email = userFace.email;
    
    final resultApi = await ApiService.checkDataUser(
        name: userFace.displayName,
        email: userFace.email,
        pass: userFace.uid,
        tipoAuth: 'F');
    
    // error api.
    if (!resultApi[0]) {
      
      _firebaseAuth.signOut();
      return {
        'acces': resultApi[0],
        'message': 'Error con datos de API, intente nuevamente'
      };
    }
    return {
      'acces': userFace.uid.isNotEmpty,
      'message': userFace.uid.isEmpty ? result.errorMessage : ''
    };
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    
    if (e.code == 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL') {
      print('Ya esta en uso el imail de facebook');
      return {
        'acces': false,
        'message': 'El email utilizado en esta cuenta ya esta registrado'
      };
    }
    
    return {'acces': false, 'message': 'Error al iniciar --->$e'};
  }
}
```

**Antes de llegar al método `ApiService.checkDataUser()` el estado de `_firebaseAuth` ya cambio a loggedin por lo que si hay un error no se muestra en pantalla y cambia a la pantalla `home` de la app con los datos de la sesión iniciada.**

Comment: Has probado hacer esa validación con la API en el onAuthStateChanged ?

Comment: @LuisUtrera Si tal cual lo he probado por eso en la primera parte del código que muestro coloque `user != null` para ahí meter la validación del a API y regresar `null` en caso de que no se valide correctamente, pero no funciona